# square data frame element shifting

Tags: python, dataframe

i have a square dataframe below

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 20 | 100 | 50 |
| NaN | 32 | 45 | 63 |
| NaN | NaN | 759 | 98 |
| NaN | NaN | NaN | 32 |

I want to shift the elements in rows to the first row after removing the nan values: expected output:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 20 | 100 | 50 |
| 32 | 45 | 63 | NaN |
| 759 | 98 | NaN | NaN |
| 32 | NaN | NaN | NaN |

PS: it will always  be a square dataframe and first row will always have no nan values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With combination of [`np.argmin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html) (to find the index of the 1st non-nan value) + [`np.roll`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) (to shift the elements by the number of places equal to the aforementioned index) routines:

```
pd.DataFrame([np.roll(row, -np.argmin(np.isnan(row))) for row in df.values], 
             columns=df.columns)
```

---

```
       A     B      C     D
0   10.0  20.0  100.0  50.0
1   32.0  45.0   63.0   NaN
2  759.0  98.0    NaN   NaN
3   32.0   NaN    NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
def shift_elements(row):
    non_nan_elements = row.dropna().tolist()
    shifted_row = non_nan_elements + [np.nan] * (len(row) - len(non_nan_elements))
    return pd.Series(shifted_row, index=row.index)

df_shifted = df.apply(shift_elements, axis=1)
```

basically remove nans from row, then add nans at the end